# changing variable of a class in node/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class that looks as follows:

```
export class Device {
  static appUserAgentTemplate = _.template('Instagram <%= version %> Android (<%= agent %>)');
  static webUserAgentTemplate = _.template(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android <%= release %>; <%= model %> Build/<%= build %>; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Mobile Safari/537.36 <%= instagramAgent %>',
  );
  deviceString: string;
  android_version: string;
  android_release: string;
  model: string;
  build: string;
  md5: string;
  uuid: string;
  phoneId: string;
  /**
   * Google Play Advertising ID.
   *
   * The advertising ID is a unique ID for advertising, provided by Google
   * Play services for use in Google Play apps. Used by Instagram.
   *
   * @see https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en
   */
  adid: string;
  id: string;
  public credentials: IAppCredentials = CONSTANTS.APP_CREDENTIALS;
  private payload: IDevicePayload;

  constructor(public username: string) {
    const chance = new Chance(username);
    this.deviceString = chance.pickone(devices);
    const id = chance.string({
      pool: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
      length: 16,
    });
    this.id = `android-${id}`;
    this.uuid = chance.guid();
    this.phoneId = chance.guid();
    this.adid = chance.guid();
    const deviceParts = this.deviceString.split(';');
    const [android_version, android_release] = deviceParts[0].split('/');
    const [manufacturer] = deviceParts[3].split('/');
    const model = deviceParts[4];

    this.payload = {
      android_version,
      android_release,
      manufacturer,
      model,
    };
    this.android_version = android_version;
    this.android_release = android_release;
    this.build = chance.pickone(builds);
    this.model = model;
    // md5 emulation for backward-compatibility. Will be removed later
    this.md5 = chance.string({
      pool: 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',
      length: 32,
    });
  }
```

and I tried creating an instance of Device via:

```
var device = new Client.Device('rovendamalianii');
```

and later in the code I wanted to change the id, adid, phoneId, and uuid by doing

```
device.id = 'somestring'
device.md5 = 'somestring'
```

however when i try to print the value again it did not change.. what is wrong ?

Comment: Try it by creating an id/md5 setter for your class

Comment: I really can't change/modify the class.. this Device class is from an npm module

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), I think, in case of a lack of setters this is a good alternative.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(device, {value: ‘str’});`

Comment: I got an error TypeError: Property description must be an object: undefined